# How to export an electron app for use in the browser

Tags: deployment, electron

I want to create my first electron app. The aim is to open, change and save a file.
With the help of a [quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start), I have created an app that works.

This is my main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})
```

This is my index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div>
            <textarea id="content-editor" style="width:100%;height:500px"></textarea>
            <input type="button" id="save-changes" value="Save changes"/>
        </div>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my preload.js

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
        const element = document.getElementById(selector)
        if (element)
            element.innerText = text
    }

    for (const type of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
        replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type])
    }

    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    const app = remote.app;
    const fs = require('fs');
    var dialog = remote.dialog;
    var filetoupdate = './configuration/config.json'
    readFile(filetoupdate);

    document.getElementById('save-changes').addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('save-file');
        saveChanges(filetoupdate);

    }, false);

    function readFile(filepath) {
        console.log('readFile ..');
        fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
                return;
            }

            document.getElementById("content-editor").value = data;
        });
    }

    function saveChanges(filepath, content) {
        var content = document.getElementById("content-editor").value;
        console.log('ssavechanged ..');
        console.log(filepath);
        console.log(content);
        fs.writeFile(filepath, content, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                alert("An error ocurred updating the file" + err.message);
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            alert("The file has been succesfully saved");
        });
    }})
```

My render.js is empty.

If I run npm start, everything is OK. The file I want to edit (currently hard coded) is loaded and I can change it. But when I open the index.html in the browser, my file is not loaded. I don't see an error.

What am i doing wrong

Comment: The browser can't support the Node API. `fs` and `Electron`

Comment: As well, you are just importing `renderer.js` so even if you wanna run and check the error below you can move this code to `renderer.js`

Comment: The electron is just executing the `preload.js` whenever its loading the renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) Opening the `index.html` in Google Chrome or another browser will not load the rest of your application. The `preload.js` script is run by Electron. To add event listeners and stuff to the DOM of your HTML, you'd need to load the contents of `preload.js` as a script as you would for normal front-end development (e.g. with a `<script/>` tag.

2) Even if you do the solution above, the app still won't be able to function in a browser. You're using the `fs` NodeJS API, which is not available in any browser environment. (In general, giving a website arbitrary disk access is a big security risk.)